# Cannot remove workspace.xml from my git

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitignore

I have tried everything but no matter what i do the workspace file (workspace.xml) keeps returning and runing my git project for me and my team.

Here are the steps ive taken:

```
$ echo '.idea' >> .gitignore
$ git rm -r --cached .idea
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m 'added idea'
$ git push
```

Now after the push i go into `PHPStorm` again and my .gitignore looks correct:

```
.idea/
user_resources/*
img/*
app_server/user_resources/*
app_server/uploads/*
app_server/database.json
app_server/custom_modules/config.json
app_server/cacheObjects/*
organizationConfig.json
```

However once i try to commit the workspace file is again added and wants to be commited.
[image]
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`git rm --cached` is used to remove things from the index, not the working tree. Use `git rm -r .idea`.

From the git docs

> --cached
>              Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Comment: i tried this sadly this did not do the trick still the same result